# Fibonacci code for loop not returning values

Tags: javascript, html, fibonacci

I'm trying to make a code where you input a number `n` and the code returns you the number in the Fibonacci sequence.
Example:
When inputting n = 1 the code returns 1, and when you input n = 2 the code returns 1, and when you input n = 3 the code returns 2, and so on.
I'm quite a beginner with javascript so I don't know exactly how to do this.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fibonacci(){
    var a, b, n, result;
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(n == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if(n == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        result = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = result;
        
    }
    document.getElementById("result").value = result;
    }
    </script>
    <form>
        <input id="n" type="number" placeholder="N">
        <input id="result" type="number" placeholder="Result" readonly="">
        
        <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="fibonacci()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i <=n cannot happen if n is null no?

Comment: add this line `n =document.getElementById("n").value`

Comment: Where exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should initialize n.
2. Then remove n==0 and n==1 from **for** loop block.
3. Update your code following,

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fibonacci(){
    var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
    var result;
    var a = 0;
    var b = 1;
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        result = n;
    }
    else{
      for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++)
      {
          result = a + b;
          a = b;
          b = result;

      }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").value = result;
    }
    </script>
    <form>
        <input id="n" type="number" placeholder="N">
        <input id="result" type="number" placeholder="Result" readonly="">
        
        <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="fibonacci()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialized n, right?

Add this line before for loop.

```
n =  document.getElementById("n").value
```

Check your browser console for errors, it shows this kind of errors correctly..

Comment: That works but my problem now is when I make n = 0 / n = 1 the code doesn't work. Also if I put n = 2 it should return 1 but it returns 2